# Getting previous/next buttons to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I typed up a quick jQuery slider box for some content. Right now I only have 3 panels or pages to it and have them cycling through when clicking "previous" or "next". The only trouble I'm having right now is getting it to disable the buttons when it gets to the end. Currently, you can keep clicking next and the container keeps moving to the left or right.

How would I go about achieving this? I thought about adding a class to the first/last slide and telling it if it has this class to hide the link? That may not be the most friendly way though. I think I would like to have it check to see if there is another child div and if not then disable the button. That way I can add more panels if I want in the future and the jQuery will know when to disable the button.

Here is what I currently have: http://codepen.io/anon/full/xdilq

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/agibud/1/edit)**

```
pagesN = $('.pages').length;
var c = 0;

function anim(){
  c = c===-1 ? pagesN-1 : c%pagesN;
  $('.pageContainer').stop().animate({left: -422*c }); 
}


$('.previous, .next').click(function(){
  var myClass = $(this).hasClass('next') ? ++c : --c;
  anim();
});
```

On click increase or decrease var `c`.
Than inside animate there's a ternary operator that will prevent `c` to go to `-1` (prev) and maintain it always in the max range (next) thanks to the modulo operator:

`c = c===-1 ? pagesN-1 : c%pagesN;`

Comment: This works great, but I don't really like how it cycles back to the beginning. Is there any way to tweak this so that the link just disappears and they are forced to click "previous"? I guess I really don't understand how it works even though you tried explaining it. :)

I'm still not very literate in JS and jQuery, haha. For now though I will use this.

Comment: @tmette sorry, I has away some time. Here is how to hide your buttons: http://jsbin.com/agibud/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

What about incrementing a variable by 1 when animation is completed or decreasing accordingly? And when this variable is at the 3rd step you hide the buttons, otherwise you show them.
Something like

```
var counter = 1;
$('.next').click(function() {
  $('.pageContainer').animate({
    "left": "-=422px"
  }, 1000, function() {
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 3){ // or panels.length
      // hide button "next"
    }
  });
});
```